# Qt QChart & QLabel alignment

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlabel, qlayout, qchart

I would like to have the same size for the two QLabels and QChart which I display inside the QWidget. This is how my design looks like:

**Qt Design**

[image: Screen Shot]

But I'm always getting smaller QChart inside that QWidget on the right side (black rectangle). As shown on this image:

**QChart**

[image: Screen Shot]

**So my code for placing the QChart inside QWidget looks like this:**

```
m_chart = new QChartView(createBarChart());
m_chart->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
m_gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui->widget);
m_gridLayout->addWidget(m_chart, 0, 0);
```

**And createBarChart return pointer to QChart:**

```
QChart* MainWindow::createBarChart()
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1374</width>
    <height>918</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>6</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>9</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>9</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>9</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>9</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>5</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="labelLogo">
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>6</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>9</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_1">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="baseSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="autoFillBackground">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">border: 1px solid;
background-color:  #CFCFCF;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="baseSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">border: 1px solid;
background-color: #CFCFCF;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="lineWidth">
            <number>1</number>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="baseSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>500</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
        <property name="title">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="replayButton">
           <property name="enabled">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>replay</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Minimum">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>start</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1374</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

This is how my UI looks like when I run it:

**UI**

[image: UI]

Comment: Do you have a layout inside a layout? If so set the margins of the inner layout to zero: `m_gridLayout->setContentsMargin(0,0,0,0)` [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)

Comment: Yes, I have. That helped a little, but still QChart's height is smaller then the height of the two other QLabels.

Comment: @lexinho021021 share your .ui

Comment: @eyllanesc It is too long to upload it here, you can dl it from https://ufile.io/nsljo . I just need all three of them to have same sizes, so any other solution with layouts is welcome.

Comment: @lexinho021021 It's not that long, I put it in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc Great! I've added the look of UI as well, it might help.